# munin phpfpm plugin

Tags: linux, debian, php, nginx, munin

I have setup PHP-FPM plugin

All graphs works except three

- PHP5-FPM Average Process Size
- PHP5-FPM Memory Usage
- PHP5-FPM Processes

## setup

/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node

```
[phpfpm_*]
env.url http://127.0.0.1/status
env.ports 80
env.phpbin php5-fpm
env.phppool www
```

command line

```
apt-get install libwww-perl
cd /usr/share/munin/plugins
git clone git://github.com/tjstein/php5-fpm-munin-plugins.git
chmod +x php5-fpm-munin-plugins/phpfpm_*
ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/php5-fpm-munin-plugins/phpfpm_average /etc/munin/plugins/phpfpm_average
ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/php5-fpm-munin-plugins/phpfpm_connections /etc/munin/plugins/phpfpm_connections
ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/php5-fpm-munin-plugins/phpfpm_memory /etc/munin/plugins/phpfpm_memory
ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/php5-fpm-munin-plugins/phpfpm_status /etc/munin/plugins/phpfpm_status
ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/php5-fpm-munin-plugins/phpfpm_processes /etc/munin/plugins/phpfpm_processes
/etc/init.d/munin-node restart
```

/var/ini/php/pools/www-php.conf

```
pm.status_path = /status
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;
    
    location ~ ^/(status|ping)$ {
        include  fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $fastcgi_script_name;
        allow  127.0.0.1;
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

test

```
cd /etc/munin/plugins && munin-run phpfpm_status
```

Comment: Anyone......? :)

Comment: What does the test tell you - nothing or? Do you have any warnings in munin-node.log?

Comment: phpfpm_average source indicates it depends strictly on `env.phpbin` and `env.phppool` - if either of these is off, even by a single character, it'll fail to work. Check ps(1) output to verify if your config matches your setup.